# To where exactly does the sarcoplasmic reticulum release its calcium when stimulated?

Tags: muscles, action-potential

I`m reading through *medical physiology* (2nd ed) by Boron & Boulpaep. On page 240 when describing the mechanism behind muscle activation, they write the following:

> After depolarization of the L-type Ca-channel on the T-tubule
> membrane and mechanical activation of the Ca-release channel in the
> SR, Ca stored in the SR rapidly leaves **through the Ca-release channel**.*

Now, according to the illustration, the Ca-release channel (sometimes linked to the L-type Ca-channels) leads back to the T-tubule, and since the T-tubule is just an invagination of the extracellular space I can`t really see why that would trigger muscle contraction.

If the Ca-content in the SR where instead released intracellularly I guess I can see how Ca could be linked to the troponin complex and the muscle contraction process could get started.

But do the Contents of the SR actually *get* released intracellularly? The text and the picture seem to indicate otherwise. I have tried searching online, but most sources just claim Ca gets released without bothering specifying where to.

Comment: I suggest using an image search (for example: [muscle sarcoplasmic reticulum calcium](https://www.google.com/search?q=muscle+sarcoplasmic+reticulum+calcium&tbm=isch)) – many images will clearly show you that the calcium is indeed released into cytosol.